# How to update only one column in a table which contain the zero value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like below:

```
$array = ['184717453','184717454','184717455','184717456','184717457'];
```

and I've a table and there is a `mobileno` coulmn. Some mobileno field contains 0 value. I want to update that field which contain 0 value using the above array.
Using first array element will update the first mobileno field which contain 0 value, 2nd array element will update the 2nd mobileno field which contain 0 value and so on...

Till now i've tried:

```
$array = ['184717453','184717454','184717455','184717456','184717457'];
$clid = count($array);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_subscription` WHERE mobileno = 0");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sql);


for ($i = 0; $i < $clid; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j<$rowcount; $j++) {
        $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_subscription` SET mobileno='$array[$i]' WHERE mobileno = 0";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
```

It's not working as i wanted. Currently it's update all the field which contain 0 value using only first number `184717453`. How can i do this please help me.

Comment: Your problem is that your query updates *all* the rows with the first mobile phone number the first time through the loop.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Yes that is the problem. Can you suggest me about the below code?

Comment: I think you need to reduce your code to a single loop and use the `LIMIT 1` clause as suggested by René Hoffmann below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have designed a solution for you, here i have assumed a field named `id` which your table `tbl_subscription` may have this field and it will work for sure, try the code below

```html
<?php
$array = ['184717453','184717454','184717455','184717456','184717457'];
$clid = count($array);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_subscription` WHERE mobileno = 0");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sql);


for ($i = 0; $i < $clid; $i++) {
    
 
  
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `id` from `tbl_subscription` WHERE mobileno = 0");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
  {
  $arr=mysql_fetch_array($sql)
  
  $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_subscription` SET mobileno='$array[$i]' WHERE id = ".$arr['id'];
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }
    
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

@Phylogenesis I just trying below code in my local machine using `LIMIT` as per René Hoffmann suggestion. But it takes too much time to execute.

```
            $array = ['184717453','184717454','184717455','184717456','184717457'];
            $clid = count($array);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $clid; $i++) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_subscription` SET mobileno='$array[$i]' WHERE mobileno = 0 LIMIT 1";
                $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

See the MySQL manual for `UPDATE`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html
The last argument `LIMIT` should do what you want to archieve.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = ['184717453','184717454','184717455','184717456','184717457'];
$clid = count($array);
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_subscription` WHERE mobileno = 0");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

$i=0;
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
     $sql = "UPDATE `tbl_subscription` SET mobileno='$array[$i]' WHERE mobileno = 0 and id = '".$fetch['id']."' ";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     $i++;
 }
```

You have also check the id in your query to update only specific row.